# Is there any Linux command to create a new file in a folder and auto create this folder if not exist?

Tags: shell, files, mkdir

I know this problem can solve by use combine mkdir and touch commands. But I want to know is there any other solution only use one command.

Comment: @don_crissti +1 You should write this as an answer, as this is the best answer so far.

Comment: @don_crissti Why you don't write this as an answer ? I will accept this is the best answer. :D
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to use a combination like this. I'm not aware that there is a special purpose command for this.

```
mkdir -p dict_to_create  # -p forces create of non-existent parent dirs
touch dict_to_create/foo.txt # touch to create the file,
                             # could use -f (force) Read, man touch
```

Comment: This is common way, but I like use only one program to do this task. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two arguments , directory name and file name. I could not think of any such command, but you can create a short script and place it in your `/usr/local/bin`.

```
cat > mkfdile  <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "$1"
cd "$1"
touch "$2"
EOF
chmod a+x mkfdile
```

I assume you need this because you want to call this from with-in another script.